# MongoDB Atlas not connecting with my golang App

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-atlas

I'm new to golang and MongoDB i've been following the official blog of mongoDb for getting started with mongo-db driver for go, and i'm not able to connect to my mongodb for some reason 
here is the code ,the error is "context deadline exceeded", thnx in advance

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    // "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)

func main() {
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb+srv://chandru:<Heregoesmypassword>@cluster0-9jkaf.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
    databases, err := client.ListDatabaseNames(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(databases)
}
```

Comment: Please include the errors you found.

Comment: Actually I've mentioned 20 seconds as threshold for the connection, but the connection isn't happening and I'm getting the error as "context deadline exceeded"

Comment: Are you aware of the IP whitelist feature of MongoDB Atlas? Basically you have to allow certain IP addresses to connect to your database.

Comment: No I did not, where should I mention the ip?

Comment: Its working now, Thnx mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause is that you have not whitelisted your IP with MongoDB Atlas
Please refer to the following guide: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/#view-whitelist-entries

Keep in mind that if you connect from your local machine, your IP address might change. You can get a static IP address from your ISP or connect to through another machine.

You can also enter 0.0.0.0/0 to allow access from any IP, but this is of course less secure.